# Query in Ruby on Rails 4 to make a selection based on the current user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and try to make the right query. But after reading the documentation and examples I don't manage to get the right query out of it. So I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**Situation**
I build an app where trainers can setup trainings, and give these trainings on several dates (the dates are called thrills), other users can subscribe for these thrills. It has the following structure: [models and needed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD8fj.png).

My models code looks like this:

```
class User
  has_many :trainings
  has_many :thrills, through: :reservations
  has_many :reservations

class Training
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :thrills
  has_many :users, through: :thrills

class Thrill
  belongs_to :training
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :users, through: :reservations

class Reservation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :thrill
  has_one :training, through: :thrill
```

- On an index page I want to show all the thrills that the current user has setup sorted by date. I think I need a query that comes up with the table in the uploaded image, and from that table I can select all Thrills where current_user.id = user_id
- On the search page I want to show only the trainings that have a Thrill that is not full (therefore I want to make a count of the Reservations)

I was thinking of something like this:

```
@thrills = Thrill.joins(:trainings).where('? = trainings.user_id, current_user.id')
```

or

```
@thrills = Thrill.where('? = @thrill.training.user_id', current_user.id).all
```

or

```
@thrills = Thrill.joins(:trainings).where(trainings: { user_id: current_user.id })
```

But unfortunately none of them works. Does someone have an idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post your models code in the question? Then I could help you with the second step..

Comment: just added, thanks

Comment: For the second part of your question you have to provide more details as nobody can guess what your logic might be to when a "thrill" is considered reserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have these two models:

```
class Thrill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :thrills
end
```

So for your index page what you can do is:

```
current_user.thrills # => ActiveRecord::Relation (can call each, map etc.)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the complication is that there is a Trainingsmodel between these two and I don't know how to deal with that. Have you a suggestion?

Comment: To answer your first question you would ofc have to add the order part so `current_user.thrills.order("created_at DESC") to have the newest on top.

Comment: Are you saying maybe a user has many thrills through trainings?

Comment: Awesome, these comments really helped me. Indeed I added   has_many :thrills, through: :trainings (instead of through: :reservations). I assume this made it possible to use the shortcut current_user.thrills. Thanks for helping me out here! @neongrau